# Rounded ends with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I can draw double lines, and I can draw rounded caps using certain arrowheads.  However, in combination they don't look as you would expect:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,scopes}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [line width = 4pt,-round cap] (0,0) -- (0,1);
  { [every path/.style = {double distance = 2pt, very thick}]
   \draw (1,0) -- (1,1);
   \draw [-round cap] (2,0) -- (2,1);
  }
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: tiny sample pictures]

I would prefer the "round cap" on a doubled line to cause the lines to curve around the end and meet, as in:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,scopes}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture} [very thick, x=1em]
  \draw (0,0) -- (0,1)
        arc [x radius = 0.5em, y radius = 0.5em, start angle = 180, end angle = 0]
        (1,0) -- (1,1);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: larger sample picture]

Obviously I *can* draw such a thing, but how can I do it with an arrow head?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use the `line cap=round` option (other permissible values are `butt` (default) and `rect`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[double distance = 0.5cm,line cap=round] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Note however that the cap extends beyond the actual line (i.e. (0,0) is at the center of the cap and not on the boundary).

---

Here is an actual arrow tip:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\pgfarrowsdeclare{open cap}{open cap}
{\pgfarrowsleftextend{+0pt}\pgfarrowsrightextend{+0.5\pgflinewidth}}
{
  \pgfmathsetlength{\pgfutil@tempdimb}{.5*\pgflinewidth-.5*\pgfinnerlinewidth}%
  \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfutil@tempdimb}
  \pgfsetbuttcap
  \pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
  \pgfmathsetlength{\pgfutil@tempdima}{.5*\pgfutil@tempdimb+.5*\pgfinnerlinewidth}%
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  \pgfpatharc{270}{90}{-\pgfutil@tempdima}
  \pgfusepathqstroke
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[very thick,double distance = 0.5cm,open cap-open cap] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Here (0,0) is at the end of the line (i.e. the boundary of the cap).

Comment: For your first solution: IIRC you can use `shorten >` and `shorten <` also if you actually don't have any arrow heads. These could be use to compensate for the overhang, i.e. by setting half the `double distance` with a negative sign.

Comment: Beautiful: that arrow tip is exactly what I want.  I will remember how to do that.